# react router and express GET conflict

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm not able to figure out how react router and express route working together.

I have this

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname) + '/server/static/index.html');
});

// routes
const apiRoutes = require('./server/routes/api');
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

The problem is my api can't use GET because it will redirect to index.html. If I remove the wildcard route, then react-router would not be able to work properly.

Comment: just change the order. Put your `api` routes first and then the `*` route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `app.get('*')` statement will match any request coming in. You can fix your problem by changing the order of the statements:

```
// routes
const apiRoutes = require('./server/routes/api');
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname) + '/server/static/index.html');
});
```

This way, any requests whose path's start with `/api` will be handled by your `apiRoutes` router, all the others are handled by the asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the order of the routes, so that your backend routes are matched first.